# Remove files from directory path B which are not found in path A on Linux

Tags: linux, directory, files

I have two paths on same system for example:

```
\mnt\a\data
\mnt\b\data
```

There are some directories and/or files in `b\data` which are not present in `a\data`. How can I remove those extra directories and/or files easily?

Further information:

- I use this to store copy my media collection on separate drives
- I rsync nightly from `a` to `b` as I am willing to accept data loss
- I use this setup instead of `mdraid` to avoid potential data loss due to power outages

Comment: @Lukasz if you are on unix/linux you don't have \ for path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are some directories and/or files in b\data which are not
>   present in a\data. How can I remove those extra directories and/or
>   files easily?

You probably want the `--delete` option of `rsync`.

One of the most common use cases for rsync is to keep two directory locations synchronised, using a command such as the following:

```
rsync -av --delete /path1 /path2
```

- `-a` Archive mode; Recursive and include permissions/owner/group/etc
- `-v` Verbose mode so you can see what's being done (useful when first testing or running manually)
- `--delete or --del` Delete files that are not present in the source